# Force password change on first login in symfony app

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-security

I am trying to implement a method to force users to change their default password on their first login in my Symfony application.

At the moment I have set up an event listener to listen for the `InteractiveLogin` event.

```
namespace App\EventListener;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;

class LoginListener
{

    private $urlGenerator;

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator)
    {
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
    }

    public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
        // Get the User entity.
        $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();
        if ($user->getForcepasswordchange()) {
            return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('force_password_change'));
        }
    }
}
```

It basically checks for a boolean flag in the user entity that is set to true for new users.  It picks up the user and the method gets to the `RedirectResponse` line but it just ends up going to the homepage (the default login behaviour).

I am not sure how to force it to not continue the login process and redirect to my password change page.

Comment: You can do a login count. If login count = 1, force password change. You can also incorporate date since login and force the user to change their password after, say... 3 months for strong password security.

Comment: Hi, I have the flag all working in the user entity, I just can't get the eventlistener to redirect to the password change page, it just goes to the homepage instead.  I think that I somehow need to interupt the authentication process if my flag is true so that authentication does not proceed to the homepage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this listening to the `InteractiveLoginEvent`.

This [event](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Event/InteractiveLoginEvent.php) does not include access to the response object, and *returning* one from the listener won't get you nowhere, since no one is waiting for the listener to return anything.

But you could do this on a `RequestEvent` listener/subscriber:

```
class PasswordChangeSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private Security              $security;
    private UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator;

    public function __construct(Security $security, UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator)
    {
        $this->security     = $security;
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => [['forcePasswordChange', 0]],
        ];
    }

    public function forcePasswordChange(RequestEvent $event): void
    {

        // only deal with the main request, disregard subrequests
        if (!$event->isMasterRequest()) {
            return;
        }

        // if we are visiting the password change route, no need to redirect
        // otherwise we'd create an infinite redirection loop
        if ($event->getRequest()->get('_route') === 'force_password_change') {  
            return;
        }

        $user    = $this->security->getUser();
        // if you do not have a valid user, it means it's not an authenticated request, so it's not our concern
        if (!$user instanceof YourUserClass) {
            return;            
        }

        // if it's not their first login, and they do not need to change their password, move on
        if (!$user->isPasswordChangeRequired()) {
            return;
        }

        // if we get here, it means we need to redirect them to the password change view.
        $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('force_password_change')));

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help.  I am further along the line but now I encounter a "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" when the redirection happens.  Can't  work  out why, even if I just redirect back to the login page?

Comment: Yeah, you are getting an infinite redirection loop. My bad. I’m on mobile right now, when I get home I’ll update the answer. But what you need to do is check that the user is not trying to visit the “change password” page, and do not perform the redirect on that case.

Comment: Cool, I will try and figure it out but I may need your updated solution later if I can't figure myself. Thanks again, very helpful

Comment: I like your method more than mine, it seems neater.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final piece of code based on the above answers and help

```
<?php

namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\RequestEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;

class PasswordChangeSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $security;
    private $urlGenerator;

    public function __construct(Security $security, UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator)
    {
        $this->security = $security;
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => [
                ['forcePasswordChange', 0]
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function forcePasswordChange(RequestEvent $event): void
    {
        // only deal with the main request, disregard subrequests
        if (!$event->isMasterRequest()) {
            return;
        }

        $user = $this->security->getUser();
        // if you do not have a valid user, it means it's not an authenticated request, so it's not our concern
        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            return;            
        }

        // if it's not their first login, and they do not need to change their password, move on
        if (!$user->getForcepasswordchange()) {
            return;
        }

        // if we get here, it means we need to redirect them to the password change view.
        $redirectTo = $this->urlGenerator->generate('changepassword', ['username' => $user->getUsername()]);
        if ($event->getRequest()->getRequestUri() != $redirectTo){
            $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($redirectTo));
        }
        return;
    }
}
```